# Why disallow binding temporary objects to non-const reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I looked through this famous language problem on stackoverflow, but found only statements like "the rule exists", not the rationale. So the question is: imagine I have a non-primitive type `obj` and do the following:

```
obj& ref = obj();
```

I'm naturally not allowed to do this, but why? As I understand it, temporary `obj` is constructed on stack memory, so why not allow modifications of this while `ref` is in scope and object still lives?

(I'm assuming `obj` would be created on stack, because if `obj` type is big enough then at some point only stack memory would be big enough to store it)

Another unclear point for me is - why allowing the same with const modifier:

```
const obj& ref = obj();
```

`obj` will still be temporary, will still live only within the scope of ref, so no apparent reasons for the behavior on two completely identical `obj`'s to differ - if they work and live identically why should we treat them differently?

I guess I will be receiving a lot of answers like "so you could construct the object in place and pass it to a function like this:"

```
void f(const obj& ref) {
    do something
}

int main() {
    f(obj());
}
```

but my question still holds, because in my understanding even if we passed in-place constructed object by non-const reference, we could freely modify something on stack without any troubling consequences - programmer should just be aware that this object is temporary and modifications will probably be lost (but might not be temporary so modifications are completely sensible!).

To simplify matters a bit, I assume `obj` type does not allocate any heap memory and is trivially constructible and copiable.

Comment: BTW it is true for primitives too. `int &x = 42;` leads to a compilation error.

Comment: To quote the most salient part of the dupe: _"It's just that the designers felt that it would cause a sufficient number of problems (probably due to the common idiom of 'out parameters') without enabling anything of similar value, so they simply made a design decision to prohibit temporaries binding to non-const references."_

Comment: In case you are unaware, you can do `obj&& ref = obj();`  (and `int&& x = 42;`)